# Can anyone help in removing trailing slash in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, url

I have added a module and requested with URL. Google is automatically adding a trailing slash to the URL. Can anyone help me resolve this in magento 2?

Should I remove this or make it work in magento 2?